# How to solve the Index error in Pytorch when I use "for x, y in Dataloader"

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I am using K-Fold method to train a Classifier. And use the KFold moudule of sklearn.

```
FK_split = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle = True, random_state=0)

for epoch in range(num_epoch):
    train_loss = 0.0
    Acc_valid = 0.0

    for train_idx, valid_idx in FK_split.split(torch_trainDataset):
        train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_idx)
        valid_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(valid_idx)
        train_dataloder = DataLoader(torch_trainDataset, batch_size=1, sampler=train_sampler)
        valid_dataloder = DataLoader(torch_testDataset, batch_size=1, sampler=valid_sampler)

        train_loss += train(model, train_dataloder, lossfunc, optimizer, train_loss)
        _, acc_valid = test(model, valid_dataloder, optimizer)
```

and the train function, test function and acc function are defined as follows,

```
def train(model, data_train, lossfunc, optimizer, train_loss):
    for x, y in data_train:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(x)
        loss = lossfunc(output, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss += loss.item()*x.size(0)
    return train_loss

def get_acc(outputs, labels):
    """caculate acc"""
    _, predict = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
    correct_num = (labels == predict).sum().item()
    return predict, correct_num

def test(model, data_test,  optimizer):
    Predict = []
    Acc = 0.0
    for x, y in data_train:
        outputs = model(x)
        predict, acc = get_acc(outputs, y)
        Predict.append(predict.tolist())
        Acc += acc
    return Predict, Acc
```

---

**However, the IndexError occurs in test process while the same method in train process works. Could you guys help me solve this problem? I attach IndexError information below. **

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [38], line 34
     30     valid_dataloder = DataLoader(torch_testDataset, batch_size=1, sampler=valid_sampler)
     32     train_loss += train(model, train_dataloder, lossfunc, optimizer, train_loss)
---> 34     _, acc_valid = test(model, valid_dataloder, optimizer)
     35     Acc_valid += acc_valid
     37 Acc_valid = Acc_valid / len(valid_dataloder)

Cell In [30], line 20, in test(model, data_test, optimizer)
     18 Predict = []
     19 Acc = 0.0
---> 20 for i, data in enumerate(data_test, 0):
     21     x, y = data
     23     outputs = model(x)

File c:\Users\Ryan\anaconda3\envs\d2l\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py:681, in _BaseDataLoaderIter.__next__(self)
    678 if self._sampler_iter is None:
    679     # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    680     self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 681 data = self._next_data()
    682 self._num_yielded += 1
    683 if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \
    684         self._IterableDataset_len_called is not None and \
    685         self._num_yielded > self._IterableDataset_len_called:
...
File c:\Users\Ryan\anaconda3\envs\d2l\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataset.py:188, in <genexpr>(.0)
    187 def __getitem__(self, index):
--> 188     return tuple(tensor[index] for tensor in self.tensors)

IndexError: index 106 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 27
```

Thank you so much if you can offer me help.

Comment: It seems you're iterating over `data_train` in the `test` function. Try fixing that maybe?

Answer (score 0):

you must use same sampler and data set.
now you are using torch_testDatase with valid_sampler.
use test_sampler  instead of valid_sampler.